# Filtering after i have done a ThenInclude in Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core

i have a few tables such as:

User -> UserRole -> Role

I am using EF Core 2

I have a query like

```
_dbContext.User.Include(x=>x.UserRoles).ThenInclude(y=>y.Roles).Where(x.Active)
```

The role table also has an active(bool) column.

How can i filter the roles to only return where active is true.
Do i need to do some complex where condition traversing through all the tables as i don't have access to the roles variable in my where clause.

Also Is this something that will be easier in EF Core 3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, EF Core doesn't support to filter in the `Include` method. It doesn't support it either in EF Core 3.x

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of the project [Entity Framework Plus](https://entityframework-plus.net/)

The EF+ [Query IncludeFilter](https://entityframework-plus.net/query-include-filter) (free and open source) allows easily filter included entities.

The `ThenInclude` is not yet supported but you just have to include the last filter to have the same behavior.

Example:

```
_dbContext.User
    .IncludeFilter(x=>x.UserRoles)
    .IncludeFilter(x=>x.UserRoles.SelectMany(y => y.Roles.Where(z => z.Active)))
```

Comment: thank you - after reading a lot of forums and stuff on github i've found that this is something that the EF team have been asked for for many years and its always something they plan on doing in future when they have finished up the important stuff. It's been on their high priority list and now sits in their backlog - probably never to be worked. Third party solutions appear to be the only way.

Answer (score 1):

Not a straight answer, mind you, but if this a "normal" requirement, that is, you always, or almost always, want to only return active roles, you may want to look at global filters, a feature that exists since EF Core 2.x. Global filters allow you to set restrictions per entity, such as "Active = true", "IsDeleted = false", etc. Global filters can be switched off, should you need to.

As to your answer, there is no obvious way to do that, other than looking at the Role entity, filtering it, and then projecting back to the root entity that you want, AFAIK.

Comment: thanks thats pretty much what i thought. I will give the global filter a try.